# convert four x,y coordinates into centroid, width height and orientation (py)

Tags: python, pygame, geometry

If i have a list of coordinates `coords = [(7, 354), (307, 339), (304, 296), (4, 311)]` for an angled rectangle. I would like to be able to convert these four points into `x,y,w,h,o` format.

How can I convert these for x,y pairs into a centroid, width, height and orientation? The centroid is easy to calculate as is the width and height. How about the orientation?

I'm ideally looking for an easy way to switch between the two. ex. `convert_to_xywho()` and `convert_to_xy_list()`

```
p1, p2 = end[:2]
p3, p4 = end[2:]
w = math.hypot(p2[0] - p1[0], p2[1] - p1[1])
h = math.hypot(p3[0] - p2[0], p3[1] - p2[1])
c = [[p1[0], p2[0], p3[0], p4[0]], [p1[1], p2[1], p3[1], p4[1]]]
centroide = (sum(c[0])/len(c[0]),sum(c[1])/len(c[1]))
```

Any suggestions on how to find the orientation. And apply such orientation to `x,y,w,h,o` to get a list of x,y pairs

Note: i'm using the PyGame coordinate system where the origin is in the top left.

Comment: What is "orientation" defined as?

Answer (score 1):

The orientation comes from the tilt of one line segment.

```
tan(theta) = (y2-y1) / (x2-x1)
```

I suspect you can finish from there.